# CakePHP delete specific session on browser close

Tags: session, cakephp

I'm trying to set up some logging in my CakePHP application and I want a specific session to delete at browser close, however CakePHP is saving the session somewhere.
What can I do to have only that specific session deleted on browser close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. See [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

> If I get you correctly, you want to know when a tab/window is
>   effectively closed. Well, afaik your only way in Javascript to detect
>   that kind of stuff are onunload & onbeforeunload events.
>
> Unfortunately (or fortunately?), those events are also fired when you
>   leave a site over a link or your browsers back button. So this is the
>   best answer I can give, I don't think you can natively detect a pure
>   close in Javascript. Correct me if I'm wrong here.